# Having trouble wrapping a span element around certain text. ( '=' and '/' )

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to wrap a `<span class="some_class"></span>` around each mathematical symbol.

I've got it to work for these symbols `*` , `+` , `-` but I can't get it to work for these `=` , `/`

I've tried using `var x = $(this).text()` instead, however that removes the `<label>` tags.

So this code works fine :

```
$('table tr td:first-child').each(function () {

    var x = $(this).html();

    var y = x.replace('*', '<span class="multiply">*</span>', 'gi').replace('+', '<span class="addition">+</span>', 'gi').replace('-', '<span class="subtraction">-</span>', 'gi');

    $(this).html(y);

});
```

But when I try adding this on

```
.replace('=', '<span class="equals">=</span>', 'gi').replace('/', '<span class="division">/</span>', 'gi')
```

it doesn't work. I think that's because there is `=` and `/` signs in the html that it is replacing too and messing everything up.

[FIDDLE FOR YOU!](http://jsfiddle.net/jpXCD/1/)
[image]
[FIDDLE FOR YOU!](http://jsfiddle.net/jpXCD/1/)

Comment: The use of flags in `replace` is non-standard but you can use a regex with flags, ie `/\*/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `text` in the `label` element instead of the `td`. Here's a way to do it more DRY:

```
$('table tr td:first-child label').each(function () {

  var x = $(this).text();

  var symbols = {
    '*':'multiplication',
    '/':'division',
    '+':'addition',
    '-':'subtraction',
    '=':'equals'
  };

  var y = x.replace(/[*\/+=-]/g, function(m) {
    return '<span class="'+ symbols[m] +'">'+ m +'</span>';
  });

  $(this).html(y);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jpXCD/5/